# unbind jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Trying to unbind a div so after it has been clicked it will not work until i bind it again, but it doesn't unbind, what i'm doing wrong?

```
$('#envio').click(function() {
  $('#mensagemenvio').html('<span style="color: blue; font-size: 10px">Enviando</span>');
  $(this).unbind('click');

  $('#saque').submit(function (){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'enviar.php',
      data: $('#sacar_btc').serialize(),
      success: function (e){
        $('#mensagemenvio').html(e);
      }
    }); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<div style="width: calc(70% - 60px); height: 25px; line-height: 25px;" class="envia" id="envio">
  <input id="envia" class="submit" type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="command"/>
</div>
```

I've tried with `off()` instead of `unbind()`, and also tried changing my jQuery version.

What i want is to disable the submit button while the php script is running, it is a slow script that takes about 5 seconds to finish, so user cant submit it twice.

Comment: Nested event handlers are rarely a good idea. Are you trying to unbind the click event on the `#envio` element, or the `submit` event on `#saque`?

Comment: What jQuery version *are* you using? From the sound of it, `.on` and `.off` are what you are looking for? `.unbind` is deprecated in jQuery 3.0.

Comment: @bsinky I'd agree although OP states they've already tried `off()` and changing the version of jQuery

Comment: If it's in an actual form note that you're providing a form submission handler that you do *not* unbind.

Comment: Rory, trying to unbind #envio, so it will not start the submit...

Comment: Jquery 3.3.1.....

Comment: @MarcoViniciusCastellari the issue is that you've already bound the submit on the first click, so you would need to unbind that too

Comment: Tried to unbind the form, doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

In the click handler you bind a function to run on form submission.

You do *not* un-bind that form submit handler.

I suspect what you *really* want to do is create a click handler that runs the Ajax, not that binds a handler to form submission. Then you *could* unbind that click-handler and it would do what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a flag to indicate that the something is being submitted like this:

```
window.isSubmitting = false;

$('#envio').click(function() {
  if (window.isSubmitting) {
     return false;
  } else {
     window.isSubmitting = true;
  }

  $('#mensagemenvio').html('<span style="color: blue; font-size: 10px">Enviando</span>');


  $('#saque').submit(function (){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'enviar.php',
      data: $('#sacar_btc').serialize(),
      success: function (e){
        window.isSubmitting = false;
        $('#mensagemenvio').html(e);
      },
      error: function() { // important the error handler to enable the event
        window.isSubmitting = false;
      }      
    }); 
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Well not working now, it just delayed the form, or my sql was lagged, still sending multiple times while the script is running

Comment: @MarcoViniciusCastellari I updated my answer, check it out

Comment: Sorry, now it's submiting like without this, 1 time per click, doesn't matter if the php script is running or no.